# Python module googletrans throwing "Max retries exceeded with url: /" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, google-translate, urllib3

My Editor is PyCharm 2017.3 and my Python version is 3.4. 
I trying to translate the word clicked on my application from english to hindi.
This application scraps words from a site and lists it.Everything is working fine with this application except the translation feature.

I have just installed googletrans library but it is giving me error that goes like max no of retries exceeded.

```
   def translate(self):
    translate=Translator()
    translate.translate(self._word, dest="hi",src="en")
```

Here is my translate function and here is the [documentation](http://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) I am referring to.

This is my Error showing in console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 326, in connect
ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\ssl.py", line 344, in wrap_socket
_context=self)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\ssl.py", line 540, in __init__
self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\ssl.py", line 767, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
timeout=timeout
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)'),))


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ROCKSTAR/PycharmProjects/Dictionary/execute.py", line 56, in getPerWordDisplay
self.query.value(4), self.query.value(5))
File "C:\Users\ROCKSTAR\PycharmProjects\Dictionary\PerWordWindow.py", line 23, in __init__
self.translate()
 File "C:\Users\ROCKSTAR\PycharmProjects\Dictionary\PerWordWindow.py", line 37, in translate
translate.translate(self._word, dest="hi",src="en")
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 132, in translate
data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 57, in _translate
token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 180, in do
self._update()
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 57, in _update
r = self.session.get(self.host)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 521, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 506, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:598)'),))

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hey, have you found the solution? I am getting the same error

Comment: No, I don't have the solution. I somehow got the complete translation for all my words and I included it in my database.

Comment: Did you solve this error? I am suddenly getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a connection error or maybe a certificate error. Its not a code error, Somehow the google server did not return a response. Try to wait some time or search for some kind of certificate, maybe they block too many requests to not overflow the server. The same issue happen to me and I wait 30min and the error was gone...